# Azure DSC Extension: What is "Module-qualified Name of Configuration"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, dsc, azureportal

While setting up an Azure DSC Extension for a VM in the Azure Portal (ARM) we find the form below.  What goes in the highlighted text-field, what module is it asking me to specify?  The xPSDesiredStateConfiguration module?  That didn't work and I can't think of any other.

The entry must match the regular expression: `"^[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$"`

Hovering over the info button gives us: "Module defining the Configuration Function, and the Function in the format 'Module\Function'".

[image: Portal DSC Extension Dialog]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is where you reference your configuration, so in your DSC file you have something like this in the file named MyDSC.ps1:

```
Configuration PythonConf1
{   
    bla-bla-bla
}
```

And in that box you would have to input `MyDSC.ps1\PythonCOnf1`. More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-dsc-overview#azure-portal-functionality